# Does Reporting Services embedded in WinForm need SQL Server?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am starting to learn Reporting Services and I read that it uses SQL Server to store the meta data. I am planning to use it in a WinForm app. Does SSRS require SQL Server to be used in a WinForm app? Can it be self contained like Crystal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LocalReport in order to make reports but you should give it directly the datasource. More over the ReportViewer Redistribuable Package should be installed !