# Crystal Report for vs 2012

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a vs 2012 professional I need to create a report that is why I installed crystal report.  I download the crystal report (CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_5) installer and installed it to my computer but unfortunately nothing happen.

Comment: Provide the detailed info

Comment: After I installed the crystal report installer I add new item in my solution but the crystal report does not appear

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695563/crystal-reports-for-vs2012

Answer (score 0):

Runtime will allow you to view reports but not to create new.
You need to install this one:
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_8.exe

Comment: I already installed that in my PC. but I still can't see the Crystal Report when adding a new item in my solution..

Answer (score 0):

If your using SQL Server then you may use SQL Server Reporting Services. Here is a [Video Tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/SQL-Server-tutorials/SQL-Server-Reporting-Services-Depth/110282-2.html) for you to get started. And here is [Getting Started](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/04/29/getting-started-with-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs.aspx) blog post for you.

Comment: I don't think I can consume the report from the SQL Reporting service to my Winforms application..

Comment: **You can**.....  
[Viewing SSRS Reports from a Windows Forms Application](http://www.resultdata.com/viewing-ssrs-reports-from-a-windows-forms-application/)  
[How to display a Reporting Services Report in a Winform application](http://geekswithblogs.net/Patware/archive/2009/03/13/130070.aspx)  
[Does Reporting Services embedded in WinForm need SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308254/does-reporting-services-embedded-in-winform-need-sql-server)